# Join 2 tables with several repeated column names- Bigquery (Error: Duplicate column names in the result are not supported)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, outer-join

I'm using big query and need to join 2 tables, table1 has 14 columns and table2 has 16. I need to retrieve the values from table 2 based on table1.FIPS and table2.fip_code.
2 of the columns are named the same  (column county and column state,table1 has more values than table2 for this columns).
I'm trying to do an outer join but failing because of the column names:

***SELECT *  FROM  `table1`
FULL outer join  `table2` 
on table1.FIPS= table2.fip_code
Error was: "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): county,state"***

I tried with alias as follow:

***SELECT
     * EXCEPT(county,state),
    county AS county_one, state AS county_two
    FROM  `table1`
FULL outer join  `table2` 
on table1.FIPS= table2.fip_code***
Error was: Column name county is ambiguous

Any advice? I can't exclude the county and state fields since I need them for my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create table alias and then use it before column names to identify from which table you are getting the columns.

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(county,state), 
  t1.county AS county_one, 
  t1.state AS county_two,
  t2.* 
FROM table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.FIPS = t2.fip_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are the duplicate, you only need to remove them from one table:

```
SELECT table1.* EXCEPT (county, state),
       table1.county as county_1, table1.state as state_1
       table2.*
FROM table1 FULL JOIN
     table2 
     ON table1.FIPS = table2.fip_code;
```

Or use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT table1.* REPLACE (county as count_1, state as state_1),
       table2.*
FROM table1 FULL JOIN
     table2 
     ON table1.FIPS = table2.fip_code;
```

Or select the values as records:

```
SELECT table1, table2
FROM table1 FULL JOIN
     table2 
     ON table1.FIPS = table2.fip_code;
```

Comment: Thank you! Option one with your syntax worked (not sure how different it is from the Except syntax I was using, but this one worked)

Comment: @Montevidean . . . Yours has `SELECT *`, which does not specify the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query:

> SELECT * FROM table1 FULL outer join table2 on table1.FIPS= table2.fip_code

Your goal:

> "I need to retrieve the values from table 2 based on table1.FIPS and table2.fip_code"

A simple way would be to alias your table names:

```
Select 
    t2.*
--, t1.*  -- you said you only need columns from t2, so I commented this out.     
From 
    table1 as t1               -- depending on the sql flavor, you may have 
    outer join table2 as t2    -- to omit the 'as' on these lines
    on t1.FIPS = t2.fip_code
Where
    [add some where stuff here if needed]
```

Comment: Same error "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): County, State". My column don't have prefixes so changing the table names don't affect the column names.